# Software sync of the XBox 360 wireless joypad

Tags: c#, xna

I want to write a program on Windows that does a sync via software between the wireless receiver and the joypad so that I no longer have to manually sync it with the hardware device.

Does anyone know if there is an API in XNA that allows to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synch is a hardware feature between the receiver and the controller. It's not a software function, so no you can't.

Comment: In most cases it's not. Hardware is "polled" by software. That means it "checks the state" of the hardware but it cannot change the state of hardware. You can almost think of this a "read only" access. It's not that it's explicitly read only for some nefarious reason - but rather, that it is read only because unidirectional communication is easier than bidirectional communication. In the case of the synch, that occurs between the receiver and the controller but it doesn't even spawn a software event for the synch action, only for when a synch is successful - then it sends "new controller".